# Create two separate columns based on two conditions from single table using ORACLE/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select, where-clause

I have a table like

```
A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 
1  1   1  1  1  1
2  2   2  2  2  2
3  3   3  3  3  3
```

and I want do the task like:

```
SELECT A2 AS B2 WHERE A1 = 1
SELECT A2 AS B3 WHERE A1 = 2
```

How should I do this?

Comment: did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN A1 = 1 THEN A2 END As B2,
    CASE WHEN A1 = 2 THEN A2 END As B3,
FROM
    yourTable;
```

Note that `B2` is as same as `A2` if `A1 = 1` else is `null` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN A1 = 1 THEN A2 END As B2,
    CASE WHEN A1 = 2 THEN A2 END As B3
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE  A1 = 1 OR A1 = 2
```